# Can not find symbol, symbol: method

Tags: java, methods, symbols

How to remove error and make method work properly?

Error:
cannot find symbol
    test.say();

symbol:   method say()

```
class Untitled {
  public void main(String[] args) {
    Student test = new Student();
    test.say();
  }
  public class Student {
    public String name = "John";
    public String studentindex = "23";
    public String group = "11c";    
  }
  public void say () {
    Student stud = new Student();
    System.out.println (stud.name);
    System.out.println (stud.studentindex);
    System.out.println (stud.group);
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: say() is not in scope of the Student class.

Comment: Its just a `}` missing?

Comment: `new Untitled().say();`

Answer (score 1):

The method `say()` is actually defined on your `Untitled` class, not your `Student` class hence the compiler warning.

You probably want to change your `main()` method to something like:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
  Untitled test = new Untitled();
  test.say();
}
```

Alternatively, you could move `say()` "inside" `Student` thus:

```
public class Student {
  public String name = "John";
  public String studentindex = "23";
  public String group = "11c";    
  public void say () {
    Student stud = new Student();
    System.out.println(stud.name);
    System.out.println(stud.studentindex);
    System.out.println(stud.group);
  }
}
```

If you take this route, then I'd suggest updating `say()` to print the current values, rather than creating a new `Student`. Something like:

```
public class Student {
  public String name = "John";
  public String studentindex = "23";
  public String group = "11c";    
  public void say () {
    System.out.println(this.name);
    System.out.println(this.studentindex);
    System.out.println(this.group);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might make `say` also use `this` instead of creating another instance inside an instance method. It's just ***very*** odd.

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking "one step at a time". I'll update my answer though.